# Text layered over image libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

So in my game so far, I am displaying different images in a scrollpane. Now on these images I want to display dynamic text that will scroll along with the scrollpane whilst staying in the same place on the image. Ive been looking around and seen different ways of doing this however Im not sure which is the best.
The ways I have seen are:
Using stack to layer the text on top of the image.
Using a framebuffer.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Although I never used [Stack](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Stack.html), I think it's the solution to your problem.

A Stack allows you to place several actors on top of each other. So the strategy would be to create several stacks. Each stack would contain an image, and the corresponding text on top of the image, and then add the stacks to the ScrollPane;

```
Image image1, image2, ... imageN;
Label label1, label2, ... labelN;
Stack stack1, stack2, ... stackN;
ScrollPane scrollPane;
Stage stage;

public Screen(final MyGdxGame gam){
    /*
    * Define all your images, labels, the scrollPane and the stage
    */

    //Add images and labels to the corresponding stack
    stack1.add(image1);
    stack1.add(label1);
    .   
    .   
    .   
    stackN.add(imageN);
    stackN.add(labelN);

    //Add the stacks to the scrollPane
    scrollPane.addActor(stack1);
    .   
    .   
    .   
    scrollPane.addActor(stackN);

    stage.addActor(scrollPane);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a stack with two tables in (one for the image and another for the overlaying information). However had problems trying to place each of the labels in the right place. I had several records through JSON data. Putting this through a for loop for each of the records displaying an image and then the label from the json data on top in the top left corner of the image. What I did to match these up for each of the images underneath was set the width and height of the image cell and then use these to set the width and height of the information table.

Comment: This is the solution for the question and it should be flagged as answer.